# Stuck on adding/toggling a css class to an html element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm new to jQuery and having a ton of trouble making things on my own. I'm trying to change the styling of  to the css class .change, but it isn't working. Really need some help. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#button').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('change');
 })
})
```

```css
html body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:#3366CC;
}
.main .container {
 margin-top:0;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5%;
}
.main h1 {
 color:white;
 font-size:100px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.main h3 {
 color:white;
 font-size:50px;
}
.main #button {
 color:white;
 background-color:red;
 padding:.5%;
 text-align:center;
 width:10%;
 font-size:25px;
 margin:auto; 
}
.change {
 background-color:black;
}
```

```html
    <DOCTYPE!html>
<html>
 <head>
        <title>Community-Help yours today</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='community.css'/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='community.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Community</h1>
    <h3>Start an initiative, gain support, build your project</h3>
    <div id="button">Get Started</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be best off doing this:

```
.button {
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
    padding:.5%;
    text-align:center;
    width:10%;
    font-size:25px;
    margin:auto;    
}
.button--changed {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Add a class for the css directly to the button.

Then toggling the `.button-changed` class. This keeps your specificity down and you won't encounter similar problems further down the line.

By adding more specificity, such as by doing `.main #button.changed` you just defer the same problem further down line. Imagine if you then need to add a second changed state for some reason?

Also, you don't now have to contain your `.button` within main in order to use it's styles and by using a class you can validly re-use the button on the page, but these are bonus point.

Here are some references to further explain ...

http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-specificity-irrelevant/

http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/

Comment: That's incredibly helpful thank you! After reading those articles, my conclusion is I should really only use the class selector yeah?

Comment: it's a good rule of thumb, personally this is the sort of approach i take to using css: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498946/are-smacss-bem-and-oocss-not-as-portable/31147366#31147366) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098498/what-is-the-best-approach-for-css-framework-of-an-enterprise-cloud-application/31300256#31300256)

Answer (score 0):

try to this css

```
.main #button.change {
    background-color:black;
}
```

because you used to this

```
.main #button {color:white;}
```

than click to **button** add class `.change` but class `.change` does not apply becuase you **button** `id` is more than power **full** you `.change` class

so that you can power full you **class** than used to this `.main #button.change`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('change');
 })
})
```

```css
html body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:#3366CC;
}
.main .container {
 margin-top:0;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5%;
}
.main h1 {
 color:white;
 font-size:100px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.main h3 {
 color:white;
 font-size:50px;
}
.main #button {
 color:white;
 background-color:red;
 padding:.5%;
 text-align:center;
 width:10%;
 font-size:25px;
 margin:auto; 
}
.main #button.change {
 background-color:black;
}
```

```html
    <DOCTYPE!html>
<html>
 <head>
        <title>Community-Help yours today</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='community.css'/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='community.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Community</h1>
    <h3>Start an initiative, gain support, build your project</h3>
    <div id="button">Get Started</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and used to **[toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**

Comment: more specificity is not really the best solution

Answer (score 0):

`.change` style is being overridden by `.main #button` style that's why the black background color is not being applied. You will see that it is being overridden from the developer tools. I suggest you read more about Specificity on CSS: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

Change `.change` to `#button.change` to make this as high priority than `#button`

Like this :

```
#button.change {
    background-color:black;
}
```

And use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` to have toggle effect.

[**Demo URL**](http://codepen.io/ran161/pen/PPWpMM)

Comment: lowering the priority of what you are trying to over-ride should always be the first port of call in css